# Calling jQuery's ready() with plugin context

Tags: this, document-ready, jquery-callback, jquery-context

My plugin allows you to specify a callback in its options. The plugin may run before the DOM is ready, but I need to make sure the callback only runs once the DOM is ready, so I'm wrapping the `callback.call()` within a `$( document ).ready()` handler.

The problem is I want to maintain the plugin's context within the callback. In other words, within the callback, I want `this` to be the plugin, not `document`.

This is what I've come up with, but I'm not sure it's really the best way.

```
function MyPlugin( element, options ){
    this.element = element;
    this.options = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );

    MyPlugin.prototype = {
        functionWithCallback: function(){
            if ( typeof this.options.callback == 'function' )
                $( document ).ready( function( plugin ){ plugin.options.callback.call( plugin ) }( this )
        }
    }
}
```

That last line is ugly, but it allows me to pass the plugin's `this` context to the callback.

I would rather do `$( document ).ready( this.options.callback )` and be done with it, but then within the callback, `this` is `document` which doesn't really help, and doesn't necessarily give me easy access to the element the plugin was called on...

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) is a perfectly solid solution for this sort of situation.

Calling functions with a different context of `this` is part of what it's for.

If you'd like a more elegant but ES5 solution (so newer browsers only) you can use [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
 $(document).ready(plugin.options.callback.bind(plugin));
```

Bind sets a function's `this` value for when you call it (as well as other parameters optionally). Here's [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/dPTSb/) of how `.bind` works.

jQuery shims it with `$.proxy` if you'd like to use *that*.

You can also do

```
$(plugin.options.callback.bind(plugin));
```

Comment: Very reassuring! Thanks. Can you show me what the call would be like using jQuery's proxy? I had thought that might be the way, but got discouraged by the syntax - I was under the impression I would be setting the context for ALL calls to ready() (as opposed to all calls to my callback)

Comment: Hmm, I think so. So my line would become: `$( document ).ready( $.proxy( plugin.options.callback, plugin )() )`? I kind of prefer `bind()`, but will that leave IE7-9 users in the dust?

Comment: I prefer bind to. Id prefer people not use IE7-9 either :) Sadly, proxy would have to do. If you feel your issue is solved please consider accepting this answer.